# Two function with same name, I want to call function which div is active

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, but have the same script method. I want to call a method, which div has `display:block`. But in this case the script method is called, which div has `display:none`.

```js
function Callme() {
  sameName();
}
```

```html
<div class="1" style="display:block">
  div 1
  <script>
    function sameName() {
      alert("1")
      //some code
    }
  </script>
</div>
<div class="2" style="display:none">
  div 2
  <script>
    function sameName() {
      //some code
      alert(2)
    }
  </script>
</div>
<input type="button" value="clickMe" onclick="Callme()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this problem by remove the latest function method which is hide and reload the html div which is active. Actually compiler get JavaScript method which is latest on the DOM having same name. So i remove the latest and on display div i render the html which have JavaScript function.

```js
function Callme() {
 $(".2").html("")

var html1= $(".1").html();
$(".1").html(html1);
sameName();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1" style="display:block">
  div 1
  <script>
    function sameName() {
      alert("1")
      //some code
    }
  </script>
</div>
<div class="2" style="display:none">
  div 2
  <script>
    function sameName() {
      //some code
      alert(2)
    }
  </script>
</div>
<input type="button" value="clickMe" onclick="Callme()">
```

Answer (score 1):

It alert you `2` because when the function or variable has the same name then the javascript runtime overwrites the previous declarations and considers the last declaration for that function or variable. In your case the last declaration is

```
function sameName(){
 //some code
 alert(2)
}
```

So, this function `sameName()` is considered having `alert(2)`.
To make your code work, you need to have that check on div `display:block` or not inside the function itself and set your conditions accordingly like:

```js
function Callme(){
  sameName();
}
function sameName(){
  let display1 = document.getElementsByClassName('1')[0].style.display;
  if(display1 === 'block' ){
    alert(1);
  }
  let display2 = document.getElementsByClassName('2')[0].style.display;
  if(display2 === 'block' ){
    alert(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="1" style="display:block">
div 1
</div>

<div class="2" style="display:none">
div 2
</div>
<input type="button" value="clickMe" onclick="Callme()">
```

Comment: yes you are right but i want to call function which div is diplay block

Comment: As this is (edit: *was*) tagged [jquery]: `if ($(".1").is(":visible")) { alert(1); }`

Answer (score 0):

Rename the functions because you will override it (execution context of the first declaration is overridden in between the second script tags)

Comment: i have 150 reports which call the same function i cant rename the fiunction

Comment: Bad architecture design then ;)

Comment: yes this is bad architecture but now we can not change this :(